# Strange memory of a pre-1990 and probably pre-1980 science fiction story: something about forced human labor and "knobs"

Tags: story-identification

Aliens forced humans to work for them and the work consisted of holding onto smooth metallic knobs which, presumably through something like electrostatic force (but probably something alien and exotic) would feel "rough" unless the human manipulates mentally (maybe physically) the knob until it feels smooth. I do not think the purpose of the work was explained.

What real-life thing this kind of reminds me of is during WW2's Manhattan project, they trained primarily women to operate the magnetic separation machines which obtained the correct isotope of uranium and this involved some process in which a beam had to be "struck" -- not sure what was going on but the interesting thing is the women themselves got good at this without really understanding (afaik) what they were doing, despite it requiring a lot of skill -- they experienced operators were much better at it than the physicists who designed the machine.

This is a photo of the "Calutron Girls" and if you read the text, I think you will see why this reminded me of the "knob" story. In fact, I could see the story in question's author having been inspired by the machine and its operators who indeed were not told what they were doing deliberately: https://www.nps.gov/articles/000/the-calutron-girls.htm

Comment: You tell us a lot more about the Manhattan Project (interesting but off topic) than you do about the story you want identified. Is it a novel, short story, comic book, movie, TV show, stage play? Is the alien sweatshop on earth, on another planet, in space? Do the aliens obtain their human slaves by conquering the earth or a human colony planet, or by abducting individuals, or hijacking starliners, or as POWs in an interstellar war? Is there a slave revolt?

Comment: @user14111 i have said all i know -- i doubt it was a novel, could have been but odds are it was a short story since most of my reading was sf short stories.

Comment: There's a short story "Idiot Stick"  (1958) by Damon Knight. Aliens hand out tools for humans to use to build the alien base, specifically including 'smoothing' out the surface. Humans don't know how the devices work but by launching a massive project (in which many researches die), they find a way of changing the devices to become weapons to defeat the aliens.

Comment: @OmnivoreNZ   sounds like the right story.

Comment: So, in the future everyone gets a knob job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented, I think this is the short story "Idiot Stick" (1958) by Damon Knight. It turns up in various anthologies, including "Invaders!" (1993). Aliens hand out tools for humans to use to build the alien base, specifically including 'smoothing' out the surface.

> The dark, hard strip, running the whole length of the area, widened as
> they moved. It was as if everything under the business end of the
> stick were instantly compressed and smoothed down.

Humans don't know how the devices work but by launching a massive project (in which many researches die), they find a way of changing the devices to become weapons to defeat the aliens.

> "Technology," said Cooley. "They underrated us; so did you." He raised
> the tool he held, careful not to touch the butt. "Ten thousand tries,
> I hear—and ten thousand dead men. All right, have it your way. I call
> that guts, too."